# How to show data from two different elements in one column?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4

How can I show data from two different elements in a single column? or if there is a way to combine two columns?

Like in following example just firstName is showing up. How can I display lastName with it too in the same column?

Folloing is the XML File 'which can't be changed':

```
<userEmail>
<user firstName="john" lastName="seena" />
<user firstName="pinku" lastName="phil"/>
</userEmail>
```

Code:

```
monitoringArray = event.result.userEmail.user;
.
.
. 
<mx:DataGrid id="monDataGrid" x="10" y="10" dataProvider="{monitoringArray}">
 <mx:columns>
  <mx:DataGridColumn width="150" headerText="User Name" dataField="firstName"
 </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It definetely could be done by using labelFunction property of the DatagridColumn.

rough example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>


    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            private var xml:XML = <userEmail>
                                    <user firstName="john" lastName="seena" />
                                    <user firstName="pinku" lastName="phil"/>
                                  </userEmail>

            private function getCombinedUserNameLabel(item:Object, col:DataGridColumn):String
            {
                return item.@firstName + " " + item.@lastName;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:DataGrid id="monDataGrid" x="10" y="10" dataProvider="{xml.user}">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn width="150" headerText="User Name" labelFunction="{getCombinedUserNameLabel}"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
```

EDIT: Arrays also shouldn't be a problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               creationComplete="application1_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
               >
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>


    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            private var xml:XML = <userEmail>
                                    <user firstName="john" lastName="seena" />
                                    <user firstName="pinku" lastName="phil"/>
                                  </userEmail>;

            private var monitoringArray:Array = [{firstName:"john", lastName:"seena"}, {firstName:"pinku", lastName:"phil"}];

            private function getCombinedUserNameLabel(item:Object, col:DataGridColumn):String
            {
                return item.@firstName + " " + item.@lastName;
            }

            private function getCombinedUserNameLabel2(item:Object, col:DataGridColumn):String
            {
                return item.firstName + " " + item.lastName;
            }           

            protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:VGroup>
        <mx:DataGrid id="monDataGrid" x="10" y="10" dataProvider="{xml.user}">
            <mx:columns>
                <mx:DataGridColumn width="150" headerText="User Name" labelFunction="{getCombinedUserNameLabel}"/>
            </mx:columns>
        </mx:DataGrid>

        <mx:DataGrid id="monDataGrid2" x="10" y="10" dataProvider="{monitoringArray}">
            <mx:columns>
                <mx:DataGridColumn width="150" headerText="User Name" labelFunction="{getCombinedUserNameLabel2}"/>
            </mx:columns>
        </mx:DataGrid>      

    </s:VGroup>

</s:Application>
```

Comment: That's great. Works fine if you use xml:XML but not working with the array i.e monitoringArray which I am using.

Comment: If it works and does what you asked for, don't forget to accept the answer, so others could save their time. Do you have tyo stick with Array?

Comment: The question was to make it work with Array. So I will accept it once I get it work with Array. Don't worry. :)  What does tyo stick refer to? Googled for it but couldn't find anything.

Comment: No problem with that. But what is in your Array? It is not clear for me. I thought your service returned String with Xml. Please clarify a little bit.

Comment: Thanks David. I was just accessing item.@firstName with @ sign still there. :P

Answer (score 0):

I guess it cannot be done without changing the XML file. The datafield property can take only one string. 
Here is the definition from adobe reference website.

```
    dataField : String
    The name of the field or property in the data provider item 
    associated with the column.
```

Comment: Thanks Anji for helping. Checkout David's answer above. It's possible. :)

Answer (score 0):

Complex columns in datagrids can be achieved with item renderers.  You can see examples on the tour de flex app from adobe.  [Tour De Flex](http://www.adobe.com/TourDeFlex)